# How create an async function to return XML element by id in node.js?

Tags: node.js, xml, asynchronous

I have created libraries.js to get xml, but I want to get a single element with id and display it in console.log. Below is my code, I am not sure how to work with the function getLibraryById(id) in order to do so.

```
//file name is libraries.js
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

var xml;
const libraryNS = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

async function loadLibraries() {
  if (xml == undefined) {
    let response = await fetch(
      "https://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/data/library-data.kml",
      {
        method: "get",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/xml"
        }
      }
    );
    //convert XML string (response.text()) to XML DOM document
    data = new JSDOM(await response.text(), { contentType: "application/xml" });
    //console.log(data);
    xml = data.window.document; //set the xml to the XML DOM document which we can query using DOM methods
    
  }
  return xml;
}
async function loadPlacemarks() {
  xml = await loadLibraries();
  return xml.querySelectorAll("Placemark");
}
async function getLibraryById(id) {
  xml = await loadLibraries();
  //LibraryInfo = xml.querySelector(id);
  return xml.getElementById("LIB02");
}
module.exports = {
  loadLibraries,
  loadPlacemarks,
  getLibraryById
};
```

Below is my async functions, I don't know how to work on getLibraryById function here to get the element.

```
app.get("/", async (request, response) => {
  let libraryList = await libraries.loadPlacemarks();
  response.render("index", { title: "Home", libraries: libraryList});
});
app.get("/library/:id", async (request, response) => {
  let libraryInfo = await libraries.getLibraryById();
  console.log(libraryInfo)
  response.render("library", { title: "Library", library: libraryInfo });
  
});
```

This is what I want to get

```
<Placemark id="LIB02">
<name>Agincourt</name>
<description>Address: 155 Bonis Ave., Toronto, ON, M1T 3W6<br/>Link: https://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/detail.jsp?R=LIB02</description>
<address>155 Bonis Ave., Toronto, ON, M1T 3W6</address>
<phoneNumber>416-396-8943</phoneNumber>
<Point>
<coordinates>-79.29342962962961,43.78516666666665</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find placemark with id is `LIB02`, you can do like this

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')
const { readFile } = require('node:fs/promises')

async function main() {
    const xml = await readFile('library-data.kml', { encoding: 'utf8' })
    const template = {
        data: ['kml/Document/Placemark[@id="LIB02"]', {
            name: 'name',
            description: 'description'
        }]
    }
    console.log(await transform(xml, template))
}

main()
```

output

```
{
  data: [
    {
      name: 'Agincourt',
      description: 'Address: 155 Bonis Ave., Toronto, ON, M1T 3W6<br/>Link: https://www.torontopubliclibrary.ca/detail.jsp?R=LIB02'
    }
  ]
}
```